# Draw polygon on google map

Tags: google-maps

i need to draw a camera view angle to a Google Map. This is relativ eays with a view angle of max 180° but if the angle is bigger i need another solution than drawing a triangle.

Here is an example what i want to achieve:

[image]

Have anybody an idea how can i make this?
The center point is the marker.

This is my code for drawing angles lower than 180 degrees:

```
    var fillTriangles = [];
    fillColorVAR = "#007caf";
    fillOpacityVAR = "";
    fillAlphaVAR = "0.25";
    strokeColorVAR = "#000000";

    var this_marker_home = marker.getPosition();
    var startPoint = new LatLon(this_marker_home.lat(), this_marker_home.lng());

    // prepare the direction for point calculation
    var pointOneDirection = parseInt(300) - ( 90 / 2 );
    var pointTwoDirection = parseInt(300) + ( 90 / 2 );

    // other points needed for the triangle
    var pointOne = startPoint.destinationPoint(pointOneDirection, 0.5);
    var pointTwo = startPoint.destinationPoint(pointTwoDirection, 0.5);

    // make a triangle with fill
    var fillTrianglePath = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(this_marker_home.lat(), this_marker_home.lng()),
        new google.maps.LatLng(pointOne.lat, pointOne.lon),
        new google.maps.LatLng(pointTwo.lat, pointTwo.lon),
        new google.maps.LatLng(this_marker_home.lat(), this_marker_home.lng())
    ];
    fillTriangles = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths       : fillTrianglePath,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor   : fillColorVAR,
        fillOpacity : fillAlphaVAR
    });
    fillTriangles.setMap(map);

    // make a line as an open stroke for the fill
    var strokeTrianglePath = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(pointOne.lat, pointOne.lon),
        new google.maps.LatLng(this_marker_home.lat(), this_marker_home.lng()),
        new google.maps.LatLng(pointTwo.lat, pointTwo.lon)
    ];
    strokeTriangles = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path         : strokeTrianglePath,
        geodesic     : true,
        strokeColor  : strokeColorVAR,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight : 2
    });
    strokeTriangles.setMap(map);
```

Comment: let me understand correctly are you trying to achieve the shape that looks above (circle minus a triangle )?

Comment: No i need a circle with a radius ov 0-X degrees. I have done it with this example:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_arc.html